# Algorithm to get group index of item in chunked array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

So I have an arbitrary array of items:

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

and when it's been chunked it looks like:

```
array.chunk(2) =>  [[0,1],[2,3],[4]];

array.chunk(3) =>  [[0,1,2],[3,4]];
```

What i'd like is an algorithm to get the index of the group that the index is in, based on the group size.

For instance, running the algorithm on each element in `array` would yield:

```
array.chunkIndex( chunkSize = 2, index = n )

0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 1
3 => 1
4 => 2

array.chunkIndex( chunkSize = 3, index = n )

0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 0
3 => 1
4 => 1
```

So running the algorithm on the index with chunkSize = 1 would always yield the original index.

How would I go about doing this? To be clear, I don't want to chunk the array, just determine which group it would be in, without looping and without built-in functions, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also in psuedo-code:

```
chunkIndex = index / chunkSize
```

It's simple integer division which means the only case you have to be careful of is languages that will return a float/decimal/real. For those cases, you will need a `floor` function to find just the integer part of the result. You may wish to handle negative values also.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. What I was attempting was way too complicated.

Comment: Yea... I def spent 3 hours trying to do more complex calculations. Thank you! Sometimes the best approach is the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

`floor(index / chunkSize)` should work!